# Could Roslyn be modded, repacked and distributed as a C# variant - say C2# - that would only kick-in and compile on specific C2# projects?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions

Strictly from a technical point of view.

There's only 1 Roslyn per VS2015 installation, yet there's multiple languages and compilers living side-by-side with it. My crude understanding is that Visual Studio activates the right extensions and compilers contextually based on the edited/compiled project type - or item type - definitions. Developers building languages for Visual Studio develop those definitions and those are installed into VS with the language.

**Q1.** Provided a language developer develops those (definitions, project and items templates, etc) then could Roslyn be modded/branded into just-another language/compiler living side-by-side with the 1 true C#/VB Roslyn?

**Q2.** If not, what are the technical limitations here?

**Q3.** If one limitation is that Roslyn's architecture and relations to VS are fundamentally different than the common 3rd party language/compilers, is there any theoretical workaround? E.g. Wrapping the modded Roslyn to make it fit into VS the exact same way common 3rd party language/compilers does it?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much you want to modify.

If you keep the core layers intact, you could conceivably create a third Roslyn language alongside C# & VB, referencing the original unmodified Roslyn core assemblies and exporting a new language, file extension, project type, etc.
You'd need to completely duplicate all of the `Microsoft.*.CSharp` projects in Roslyn.

In practice, that is unlikely to work, because far too many of the types you'll need to inherit & export are internal (and exposed to other parts of Roslyn itself via `[InternalsVisibleTo]`).

Alternatively, you could fork the entire Roslyn codebase as a completely new set of extensions.  You'll need to change all of the assembly & namespace names so they can load side-by-side with the original projects, and you'll need to change every single GUID and unique ID to distinguish VS-wide exports from the original extensions.

That will be a lot of work, and will give you lots of headache as VS APIs change (Roslyn's editor & project system layers are tightly coupled to VS, using APIs that are not officially supported and are highly subject to change).  And it won't be easy to pull in changes from the original upstream codebase across your renames.

Comment: What if I'm only thinking of incremental features to C#? A superset variant of C#. Such as adding new keywords (e.g. access modifiers) and implements their effects through C# code generation at build time? Do you think this modded Roslyn could be packaged, distributed and then run side-by-side with the standard C#/VB Roslyn? Because if so, very interesting things could happen.

Comment: @Mart: Running side-by-side will require the tremendous effort described in my second option.  This is very much not supported.

Comment: If you only want to run YOUR version of the C# compiler inside VS that can be achieved easily. In fact that's what the Microsoft.Net.Compilers nuget package does. It ships a csc.exe and in a .props file it overrides the `CscToolExe` property. But this won't help you with IDE features, etc.